# Compress with tar and validate then upload to S3 and validate

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, tar

I am compressing a DB backup file, then uploading it to S3.

It works and uploads successfully but I don't know how to validate it's successful. As I'm not getting any output.

```
COMPRESSING_0=`tar cvzf - $BACKUP_PATH_DB/$YEAR_MONTH/${DB_NAME}-${DATE}.bak` | UPLOADING_TO_S3_0=`aws s3 cp - s3://db-bckp/db/${DB_NAME}.tar.gz`
```

Question:

- 1: How can I validate a tar compression from pipeline?
- 2: How can I validate it's successfully uploaded to S3 (as it's not returning anything)?

Comment: If it " works and uploads successfully", what do you want to validate exactly? Seems everything is fine.

Comment: @Marcin that it was successful. So I can schedule it in corn… The S3 file upload doesn’t return anything for example.

Comment: You mean like some hash check sum, or whether the file exists after the upload in S3?

Comment: @Marcin Whether it was successfully updated. I don’t want to hash the uploaded file. Just want to verify the tar compression was successful.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused by your code. Are you sure that it works? Because from what I understand it will not work, at least not the way you think it works.

Comment: Well it does compress the file and upload it. So it works. But I need to manually verify...so want to automate that\

Comment: Yes, it will upload the compressed file, but the uploaded file has 0 bytes in size. Maybe it would be good to provide full details how you run the code? What OS, bash version?

Comment: @Marcin Its not 0, at least thats what S3 says. `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)` on `CentOS Linux 7 (Core)`

Comment: Can you please double check that the code you are using is exactly same as in the question? You can copy and past it in a terminal without any modifications to run successful? I try to run it, and it does not work (after I set all bash variables you use). Thus I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Are you sure it is uploading the result of the `tar` command? Wouldn't the result of the first command be assigned to the `COMPRESSING_0` variable? There's possibly nothing to pipe to the next command. For example, if I run ``"COMPRESSING_0=`echo hello` | echo``, nothing is printed on the screen.

Comment: @Marcin I have more files that I'm comprising together into one. Other than that it's all the same.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Well it works for me. Just dont know how to validate it...

Answer (score 0):

When you work with pipes into bash, if you want to read each command return codes, you will use the `PIPESTATUS` array variable.

`PIPESTATUS` is define for each executed command (with or without pipe use).

Here an example:

```sh
$ x=`ls /root >/dev/null 2>&1` | y=`lsx / >/dev/null 2>&1`
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}
2 127
```

- The `2` is the return code for first command (`ls`)
- The `127` is the return code for second command (unknown `lsx`)